# inline-block elements just flow out instead of going to the next line

Tags: php, css, dompdf

When using [DOM PDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), the elements just flow out of its parent instead of going to the next line after being rendered, something like this:

```css
* {
  font-size: x-small;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.child {
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
 <div style="background-color:pink;">
  <div style="background-color:red;float:left;width:50%;">PARENT</div>
  <div style="background-color:green;float:left;width:50%;">
   <div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div><!--
   --><div class="child">CHILD</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Rendered output from DOM PDF:
[image: rendered output]

I was expecting something like this *(output from the browser)*:

[image: browser output]

Already tried using `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`, but the elements just overlapped with each other, so I opt for the latter.

What other ways can I do to achieve the same output as the browser's?

Comment: Which's the element with `background-color:blue`?

Comment: Tried your code and it's working check here https://jsfiddle.net/indefinite/3pxfq0ec/3/

Comment: @indefinite — The question is about DOM PDF, not a web browser. Did you test that code in DOM PDF?

Comment: @Quentin Oh sorry about that.

Comment: @RyanNghiem That's the first child, I just made it the same as its siblings so the color is now orange instead of blue

Comment: I think you might try to reset some element with `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;`, and `box-sizing: border-box` this might fix your issue

Comment: Guess the fact that there’s no whitespace between the elements might prevent it from breaking into lines properly? Try and remove those comments, put every child on a new line (or at least a space between them), and counter the spacing that causes in rendering by using `font-size:0` on the parent (reset for children.)

Comment: @04FS Unfortunately, it didn't work. Although the `font-size: 0` is a new knowledge for me, thanks for that.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of “overlapping” you get when floating the children? (And would that again be something that only shows when rendered using dompdf, but not in a browser?)

Comment: I mean that the elements just stacks to each other, and yes, specific to dompdf.

Comment: Why not use a more modern approach with grid

Comment: @RudiUrbanek It is not supported in dompdf

Comment: Issue created on project page here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1943